# Modifying opacity in Flutter Flame Tiled layer not working

Tags: flutter, flame

So I'm trying to fade out a Tiled Layer in Flutter Flame and I'm finding that regardless of what value I set on the layer's opacity property the opacity is not updating.

This is what I have so far:

```
class HiddenSwitch extends PositionComponent
    with HasGameRef<TheGame>, CollisionCallbacks {
  HiddenSwitch({
    super.position,
    super.size,
  });

  bool visible = false;
  bool offLayerVisible = false;
  bool onLayerVisible = false;

  double lifeTime = 0.8;
  double fadeTime = 2;
  double elapsedTime = 0.0;
  bool initiateFade = false;

  void collidedWithPlayer() {
    initiateFade = visible = !visible;
  }

  double map(
      double value, double start1, double stop1, double start2, double stop2) {
    return start2 + (stop2 - start2) * ((value - start1) / (stop1 - start1));
  }

  @override
  void update(double dt) {
    // Update elapsed time
    elapsedTime += dt;

    if (initiateFade) {
      final backgroundOff = game.tileMap.getLayer("BackgroundOff");

      if (backgroundOff != null) {
        // Calculate the opacity based on the elapsed time and fade time
        double opacity = 1.0 - (elapsedTime / fadeTime).clamp(0.0, 1.0);

        // Set the opacity of the BackgroundOff layer
        backgroundOff.opacity = opacity;

        // Check if the opacity has reached 0, indicating the end of the fade
        if (opacity <= 0.0) {
          initiateFade = false;
        }
      }
    }

    super.update(dt);
  }

  @override
  FutureOr<void> onLoad() async {
    add(RectangleHitbox());
    return super.onLoad();
  }
}
```

Comment: As of now flame_tiled does not support dynamic changes to the layer opacity. You can open a new feature request on the repo here: https://github.com/flame-engine/flame/issues/new/choose